How to access the top level/enclosing class instance having the instance of the inner class
NOTE: I'm not talking about the way of accessing the enclosing class FROM the inner class, that is not the problem at all. What I'm talking about is the following:
class TopLevel {

    class InnerClass {
    }
}


// in some other class A.java
public void execute(InnerClass ic) {

}

Here, in the execute() method, we have the instance of the InnerClass passed as an argument. So what I actually want is to access the instance of Enclosing class, inside which the InnerClass instances that was passed to execute() was created.
How can this be achieved?

I've found a pretty good solution. If you have access to the source code, then something like this is possible:
class TopLevel {

    class InnerClass {
        // just declare the method that exposes the enclosing instance
        public TopLevel getEnclosing() {
            return TopLevel.this; 
        }   
    }
}

// in some other class A.java
public void execute(InnerClass ic) {
    ic.getEnclosing().doSomething();
}



There is no standard way to do it.
You need to add method that returns outer class to your inner class.
